# Django-How do i get the HTML template to show data from the two models?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views

So i'm creating a to-do app. How do I get the html view to show the tasks? I tried to show the name of the tasks but it's blank. So far, it only shows the board name and the user who created it. 
Here is my code so far:
**Models.py**

```
class Board(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Board")
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Task(models.Model):
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    assigned_to = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**views.py**

```
def board_post_detail(request, board_id):
obj = get_object_or_404(Board, id=board_id)
taskobj= Task.objects.filter(board=obj)
context = {"object": obj, "tasks": taskobj}
return render(request, 'boards/board_post_detail.html', context)
```

**board_post_detail.html**

```
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ object.name}}</h1>
<p> {{tasks.text}}<p>
<p>Created by {{object.admin.username  }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I've just realised I need to use a for loop. Whoops!

Answer (score 0):

I realise that I needed to use a for loop to iterate throught the tasks.

```
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ object.name}}</h>
    <ul>
        {%  for task in tasks %}
            <li>{{ task.text }} is assigned to {{ task.assigned_to }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
<p>Created by {{object.admin.username  }}</p>
```

{% endblock %}